# Dataframe overwrite first result

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a dataframe imported from json, which I would later transfer to Excel. The problem is  that (df1) write new results over the first result (so basicaly all the results are deleted in the end except the last one). How can I fix it to get all the data?

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://api.gateio.la/api2/1/feelist')
lista = (r.json())
for key, ad in lista.items():
    sy  = ad['symbol']
    no  = ad['no']

    df0 = [[sy]]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame((df0), index=[no])

print(df1)
```

My results:

1981    SFM

Desided:

1  GT
2  CNYX
3  USDT
...
1981    SFM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rewriting `df1` each for-loop iteration. Instead, try to leverage `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = requests.get("https://api.gateio.la/api2/1/feelist").json()


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(ad["symbol"], ad["no"]) for _, ad in data.items()],
    columns=["Col1", "Col2"],
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            Col1  Col2
0             GT     1
1           CNYX     2
2           USDT     3
3       USDT_ETH     4

...

1977         BTL  1978
1978    LIQUIDUS  1979
1979       DEHUB  1980
1980         SFM  1981
```

Comment: It works, but I wanted to add ad["withdraw_fix_on_chain_ETH"]. The problem is that the key is only occasionally present. That's why I have a KeyError. I tried the .isna, .ifllna if else method. But I failed to add. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @smetfor You can try `ad.get("withdraw_fix_on_chain_ETH")` - it will get `None` if the key doesn't exist.